# Why would Trusted Execution Engine wake up computer?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management

Today, I was investigating why my Tablet PC/2-in-1 with Windows 10 on it had so little battery life while in sleep mode and I found a very interesting discovery - the computer had been waking up from the Intel trusted execution engine! When I invoke `powercfg /lastwake`, I see that the reason for wakeup is the TXE. Furthermore, if I look into Event Viewer, I see that every single wakeup is caused by the TXE! However, the Trusted execution engine is not listed in devices allowed to wake up the Tablet, which is strange. I have no currently enabled wake timers. 
Related commands output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /LASTWAKE
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 2
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Device
    Instance Path: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0F18&SUBSYS_72708086&REV_0F\3&11583659&0&D0
    Friendly Name:
    Description: Intel(R) Trusted Execution Engine Interface
    Manufacturer: Intel
  Wake Source [1]
    Type: Device
    Instance Path: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0F18&SUBSYS_72708086&REV_0F\3&11583659&0&D0
    Friendly Name:
    Description: Intel(R) Trusted Execution Engine Interface 
    Manufacturer: Intel
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /DEVICEQUERY wake_armed
Myš kompatibilní s technologií HID
Zařízení klávesnice standardu HID (001)
Realtek I2S Audio Codec
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /WAKETIMERS
There are no active wake timers in the system.
```

Why would the TXE want to wake up the computer, why does it succeed (given that it's forbidden to) and why is the only reason that the computer ever woke up?